# When programmatically assigning the data source of a GridView, can you still use the VS designer to set up it's columns?

Tags: asp.net

Any examples? The reason I do not use a data source control is that I find them harder, not easier than writing code because of a lot of casting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vs designer can only be at compile time so the answer is no